# Need an idea for cycled sending function

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, date

I've got a scanning date which is set by application users. I need an mechanism, that will check every day, after midnight the current date, and match it with the date entered in format 0000-00-00 in the database, and if match, will send an e-mail. The function need to run every day, at midnight. Any ideas how can achieve the cycled function run it in a professional way?

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron is perfect tool for this kind of scripts.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron